# accessing remote web services(cross domain applications) using jquery jsonp

Tags: web-services, jquery, json

Here is My code ..could anyone please solve this problem..I was struggling from morning..below code is not working.Actually i should get the data when we send jasondata as input..but i am getting error.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myQuerySuggestions() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('txtsearch').value;
                    searchText = "'" + searchText + "'";
                    var jasonData = "{" + 'CountryName:' + searchText + "}";
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?jsoncallback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonpCallback: 'blah',
            data:jasonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert(status+" status");
            },
            error: function () { alert("error"); } 
        });

    }
    function blah(data) {
        var result = (typeof data.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data.d + ')') : data.d;
        $('#summary').html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');
        $('#summary').html(result);
    }

</script>
 </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <label for="txtsearch">
        Enter country:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtsearch" size="43" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="myQuerySuggestions();return false;" />
    <div id="summary" runat="server"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My First question, when I saw your code above, was: Does the service support returning json data and recognizes jsonp format?
I could not find any evidence that json is supported as a response data structure...

If you have gotten information from this service provider that the API does in fact support jsonp, can you post the expected format?

Also,
It would be good to for you to also post the Error you are getting (in detail, if possible)... It will helps us to help you. :)

Paul.

Comment: actual output will be in xml format..

Comment: errors are parse error and jquery123123132131 not defined

Comment: Sounds like, then, the webservice you are trying to use does not support jsonp, so you can't do what you are attempting.